# cual es el departamento que mas salario promedio devenga

Tags: sql, plsql

```
select department_id 
into v_departamento
from employees
where salary = (select max(salary) from employees);
```

se que lo estoy haciendo mal porque estoy sacando el departemento que mas salario gane y necesito es el que mas salario promedio gane.

```
select Max(promedio) 
from (select avg(salary) promedio 
from employees
group by department_id);
```

creo que ya tengo parte de la solución ya se el mayor promedio por departamento, pero no se como traer el departamento que devenga ese promedio.

Comment: Tu lo estás diciendo... solo debes corregir una cosa que esta entre `( )` .. si ahora solo estás seleccionando el max(salary) , es decir, el maximo salario... ¿Como debes cambiar eso para obtener el max(promedio)? .. y si no sabes eso... ¿Como obtienes el promedio de salarios de cada departamento? ... si me muestras que puedes hacer una de esas dos cosas, te ayudo con la respuesta final.

Comment: Para obtener el máximo salario promedio, primero debes obtener el salario promedio, ya luego puedes pensar en el máximo.

Comment: select Max(promedio) from (select avg(salary) promedio from employees group by department_id ); una parte de la respuesta pero aun no consigo saber como muestro el departamento que devenga ese salario, ayuda por favor

Comment: La respuesta tiene que ir en el campo respuesta, si ninguna de las respuestas que te dieron soluciona el problema... ademas, deberias agregar la base de datos como etiqueta...

Answer (score 1):

Con el segundo ejemplo, estás en lo correcto !!

```
SELECT MAX(promedio) 
from (select avg(salary) as promedio 
from employees
group by department_id);
```

Ahora, si quieres traer otra columna, solo agregala a la consulta :3

```
SELECT department_id,  MAX(promedio) 
from (select department_id , avg(salary) as promedio 
from employees
group by department_id);
```

Ahora, si esto llegase a arrojarte un error, que le falta un alias a la tabla, solo debes agregar un nuevo nombre a la tabla derivada.

```
SELECT department_id,  MAX(promedio) 
from (select department_id , avg(salary) as promedio 
from employees
group by department_id) as nuevaTabla
```

Comment: aun no me funciona estoy trabajando en oracle con el esquema hr el department_id esta tambien en la tabla employees, necesito es traer solo el departamento que devenga ese salario promedio mayor.

Comment: A ver a ver... no entiendo bien.. no necesitas el promedio mayor... solo el departamento con el mayor promedio ??

Comment: necesito saber cual es el departamento que mas salario promedio devenga.

Comment: pero si ahi te lo deje, cuando muestras el department_id, sabes que departamento es.

Comment: SELECT department_id,  MAX(promedio) 
from (select department_id , avg(salary) as promedio 
from employees
group by department_id);
--con esta me aparece un error de "not a single-group group function"

Comment: Es lo que te menciona el otro sujeto, sql necesita de only_full_group, por lo que puedes hacer el limit

Comment: amigo, muchas gracias por tus respuestas. para la version de oracle 11g como  que  no funciona el limit pero lo solucione de la siguiente forma.                            
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT max(promedio) promedio, department_id
FROM (
    SELECT AVG(salary) AS promedio, department_id 
    FROM employees GROUP BY department_id
)  t1
group by department_id
ORDER BY 1 DESC)
where  rownum = 1;

Comment: ohh rownum, perfecto ! (y)

Comment: sql no, @Excorpion, las versiones viejas de mysql que lo hacian mal...

Answer (score 1):

Un usuario ya dio una respuesta aceptable. Sin embargo, esta no toma en cuenta que algunos servidores SQL están configurados con el modo only_full_group_by, de manera que la consulta que proponen va a generar un error.

Aquí te dejo una alternativa:

```sql
SELECT promedio, departamento
FROM (
    SELECT AVG(salary) AS promedio, department_id AS departamento
    FROM `employees` GROUP BY department_id
) AS `alias_del_select`
ORDER BY promedio DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Y que implica el modo only_full_group_by

Comment: Hola necesito el department_id que mas salario promedio devenga , el department_id tambien se encuentra dentro de la tabla employees . estoy trabajando con oracle es el esquema hr , a lo que me refiero es que debería aparecerme solo el department_id que debenga ese salario promedio máximo         
 SELECT MAX(promedio) 
from (select avg(salary) as promedio 
from employees
group by department_id);  intente de esta manera

Comment: cuando decis servidores sql, esta mal. No hay servidores sql. Sql es el lenguaje de los motores de bases de datos relacionales. Querras decir mysql, como motor, que es la unica base de datos que te deja hacer esos group by que estan mal.

Comment: Pues entonces hay que poner una queja con Microsoft para que su producto deje de llamarse "SQL Server", y también hay que meter un pull request a los repositorios de MySQL en Linux porque claramente hay un paquete que se llama mysql_server y otro llamado mysql_client. Vaya manera de lucirse con tecnicismos.